# Make a new ComponentFramework.PropertyTypes.Dataset using JSON from Web API call

Tags: powerapps, pcf, powerapps-component-framework

I'm trying to make a PCF that shows data from an API call.  The API returns a JSON.

Is there a way to convert this JSON to a ComponentFramework.PropertyTypes.Dataset?

The Dataset has features like paging for example.